# Does a rational matrix have a rational inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, inverse

To be more specific than the title:

Let $A$ (an $n\times n$ matrix) be over $\mathbb Q$, so of course $A$ is over $\mathbb R$ too.
Now, how can I prove that if $A$ is invertible over $\mathbb R$, it's also invertible over $\mathbb Q$?

I'm not sure that what I've tried is enough to prove it:

> If $A$ is invertible over $\mathbb R$ so the $\det(A)\neq 0$ so its also not equal to zero over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @JohnHughes I said that if A is invertible over R so the det(A)!=0 so its also not equal to zero over Q isn't it? but im not sure its enough ?

Comment: That's pretty much enough, yes.

Comment: Probably the shortest answer is "Cramer's Rule". (But that's more or less Hagen's answer anyhow.)

Comment: Since I personally don't like determinants (as they are very expensive in numerical applications), I suggest using Gaussian Elimination as proof. (Same reasoning as Hagen: row addition, multiplication of rows etc. )

Comment: @P.Siehr: Since this question was purely theoretical (not "how do you *compute* the inverse over $\Bbb Q$", but "does it exist?"), I felt that a determinant-based answer was reasonable, although I understand your view. I hesitate to think of how you might choose to state the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem, though. :)

Comment: @JohnHughes True. And to clarify things: Your answer is very good. //  One other reason for my comment is, that Gaussian Elimination is something that everyone is (should be) very familiar with. If you do the algorithm in your mind on any matrix $A∈ℚ^{n×n}$, you can clearly see that you only do "harmless" operations. And the answer gets quite intuitive.

Comment: Oh, I agree completely. I'm a great advocate for Gaussian Elimination in general. I just liked the short answer, and the opportunity to poke a little fun about the C-H theorem. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The entries of $A^{-1}$ are obtained from the entries of $A$ by a lot of multiplications and additions of these entries (which is "harmless", i.e., will never take us out of $\Bbb Q$), and then dividing by $\det A$. We already know that $\det A\ne 0$, so this division is possible. But also $\det A$ is obtained from the entries of $A$ by harmless additions and multiplications, so $\det A\in\Bbb Q$ in our case. Of course, division by a (non-zero) element of $\Bbb Q$ still cannot take us out of $\Bbb Q$. So indeed all entries of $A^{-1}$ are rational.

The argument generalizes: if all entries of an invertible $A$ are in some *ring* (e.g., $\Bbb Z$), then all entries of $\det(A)\cdot A^{-1}$ are also in that ring.

Comment: Re the generalisation: Aren't you saying already that $A$ is invertible as a matrix over some ring, which means that all entries of $A^{-1}$ are in that ring, as well as $\det(A)$? Did you mean "all entries of an invertible $A$ are in some _subring_"?